# ArgoCD with Istio returning 404

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, istio, argocd

Hi I am using Istio for traffic management (among other things) on AKS. Because I am terminating SSL on the gateway (no passthrough), I add the --insecure and --staticassets flags to the Deployment. I have also set the server.basehref value to /argo. Whenever I visit the /argo I see 404 responses in the Network tab on Chrome, what am i doing wrong

I am also currently using the gateway to expose Kibana, Kiali and Keycloak. I have also tried adding a DestinationRule to disable TLS on the argocd-server service. In addition to a few 404s (static assets like css)

Here is the Istio specs:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: global-gateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - <FQDN>
    port:
      name: http
      number: 80
      protocol: HTTP
    tls:
      httpsRedirect: true
  - hosts:
    - <FQDN>
    port:
      name: https-443
      number: 443
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      credentialName: wildcard-tls
      mode: SIMPLE
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: argocd-server
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  hosts:
  - <FQDN>
  gateways:
  - istio-system/global-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/argo"
    rewrite:
      uri: "/"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: argocd-server.argocd.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
```

Comment: have you configured the argo-cd service to run in `insecure` mode? if not, it may not be accepting port 80; can you post the manifests for the deployment as well as service

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to set the `--basehref` and `--rootpath` flags on argocd-server. I also removed the rewrite rule.